# Preserve Permissions when adding files to a Samba share

Tags: macos, ubuntu, permissions, samba, zfs

I have a Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6) client that is connected to an Ubuntu server (18.04 LTS) running Samba, sharing a ZFS pool. Everything works great, except that whenever I add a file to the server, the permissions are changed.

For example, here's foo.txt on the mac:

```
$ ls -l foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 foo.txt
```

When it is clicked and dragged to the server, the server copy changes the attributes:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt
-rwx------  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt*
```

Copying the file from the server back to my Mac retains those permissions:

```
$ ls -l ./Copied\ From\ Server/foo.txt
-rwx------  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 ./Copied\ From\ Server/foo.txt*
```

I want to have the file permissions retained when copying to the server, i.e.:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt
```

All the `ls -l` commands were executed on the Mac client.

Comment: If these are considered "attributes" "flags" "ACLs" i'm sorry if i got that wrong, to my understanding they're all the same.

Comment: also (kinda off topic), what does `@` mean at the end of the permissions? i see that on files sometimes on my Mac, i.e. `-rw-r--r--@ ...... file.txt`

Comment: You'll probably get MUCH better answers than mine, but here goes...  First, the "@" at the end of the permission flags represent special permissions (a separate ACL), not to be confused with an "@" after the filename, which says the file is a symbolic link.  Regarding your real question, though, consistent permissions require consistent user-management/authentication between Mac and NAS.  A simple NAS might not have that at all, a high-end one should offer something like this.  For me, I had to live with "wide-open" perms on my NAS, 1 of the many reasons why I switched to USB...

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @jimtut. I originally used USB hard disks to store my data, until my storage needs became too great. My server has ~60TB of usable space; definately not something that could be solved over USB (well, maybe). my NAS is just a dell poweredge with two 24-bay netapp disk shelfs connected to it. i log into the server on my Mac by 1) Finder->Go->Connect to server 2) enter server IP, click connect 3) login to user account stored/configured on server

Comment: Then you must be running your own OS (Linux or Windows) on the Dell, so you should be able to control user-management on the NAS/SMB side, that's good (meaning another user/computer on the network would need to your NAS/SMB credentials to access your files).  I would think the "world-readable" bit (the 3rd "r" in your Mac's local permissions) would be something you could control in the SMB settings, but I don't think the middle "r" (group read access) is possible.  There's no "group" definition for the SMB protocol that I know of (not an expert, just have used this a bit too).

Comment: @jimtut yes my server is running ubuntu